# Marshalling nested structures

Tags: c#, marshalling

I have two C++ structures as shown below.I have to get the structure when calling a DLL method from C#.

For example, lets define them as below in C++ code:

```
struct A
{
    int count;
    struct B;
}

struct B
{
    char* id;
    char* name;
}
```

C++ code return the below method

```
A* GetData();
```

A method that I need to call from C# has the following signature:

```
IntPtr GetData ();
```

This method gives the pointer to structure A filling count in struct A, id and name from struct B.

In C# I define these structures as classes:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

class A
{

    public int count;
    public IntPtr B;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]

class B
{

    public string id;
    public string name;
}
```

I have created a C++ dll to call from C#.

When I try to read data from the nested structure `(A->B->id)` I get a read violation error `(AccessViolationException)`.

How can I marshal the nested structure so I will be able to read it in the C# method?

My C# code is as below

```
[DllImport("Win32Project.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]

public static extern IntPtr GetData();

A setting = new A();

setting.B = new IntPtr();

IntPtr deviceSettingptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(A)));

IntPtr settingsInfoptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(B)));

Marshal.StructureToPtr(setting, deviceSettingptr, false);

Marshal.StructureToPtr(setting.B, settingsInfoptr, true);

setting.B= settingsInfoptr;

deviceSettingptr = GetData();

setting = (A)Marshal.PtrToStructure(deviceSettingptr, typeof(A));

B info = (B)Marshal.PtrToStructure(setting.B, typeof(B));

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Setting count={0}", setting.count));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Setting id={0}, Setting name={1}", info.id, info.name));
```

How do I access the members of struct B having id and name?

Comment: Wait, so is `A.b` a pointer to `B`, or just `B`?

Comment: The A.B member is a struct, not a pointer.  You must declare it as B instead.  The strings in B are a very significant memory management problem, somebody has to release them again.  The pinvoke marshaller cannot do it, you must therefore declare them as IntPtr and use Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi().  How you are going to release memory, well, good luck.  Much the same for the return value of GetData(), also high odds that this is a dangling pointer.  Improve the C++ code first, it is not usable as-is.

Comment: I declared strings in struct B as IntPtr and used below to get back the data. string id= Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(info.id);                                                         But this is returning empty string.

Comment: I got the string values after declaring as IntPtr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted looks a little weird. Everything before the line

```
deviceSettingptr = GetData();
```

seems irrelevant. You did not show what `GetData()` does, but it seems that this method is *returning* a pointer to a structure. So at first read the structure (presumably an `A`):

```
deviceSettingptr = GetData();
setting = (A)Marshal.PtrToStructure(deviceSettingptr, typeof(A));
```

(At this point, anything you did to the variable `setting` before becomes obsolete).

And now you want (probably) to read a structure of type `B` from the memory pointed to by `setting.B`:

```
B info = (B)Marshal.PtrToStructure(setting.B, typeof(B));
```

In your code you used `settingsInfoptr` instead that was not properly set.

Now you can access the properties `id` and `name` of `info`:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Setting count={0}", setting.count));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Setting id={0}, Setting name={1}", info.id, info.name));
```

---

Note that probably someone should *release* the memory allocated by `GetData()` again.

Comment: B info = (B)Marshal.PtrToStructure(setting.B, typeof(B)); Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Setting id={0}, Setting name={1}", info.id, info.name));                                                                                                        info.id and info.name gives pointer value and not the string value.